# Use Firebase application for different flavors

Tags: android, firebase

I have a main package which called "project" and a flavor called "flavor"

[image]

The error " No matching client found for package name ..." occure when project tries to build and didn't find the project package name in google-services.json. In my case, "project.flavor" is missing which prevent project from building.

If i try to add ".flavor" manually in google-services.json file , project will build normally, and android app will start, but authentication with Firebase won't work.

Can we use same google-services.json file for different project flavors ?

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found a solution.

For Firebase to work with flavor, i added new Firebase application using "FirebaseConsole" and put it's package to "project.flavor", added my generated SHA-1, then downloaded the .json file and imported it to my flavor package inside ANdroid Studio.

Works like a charm <3 <3 :D

Conclusion : Each project flavor needs it's own Firebase application, and it's own google-services.json

Comment: this is also detailed in https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Thank you for the info. I didn't know what is a flavor back then, when i watched the tutorial video, and read the documentation.